# Lazy<T> properties Thread safety

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading up Lazy and I saw this caution note on Msdn [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Making the Lazy object thread safe does not protect the lazily
>   initialized object. If multiple threads can access the lazily
>   initialized object, you must make its properties and methods safe for
>   multithreaded access.

Does this mean we have to apply thread safety measures to all properties? If yes, then what purpose does the Lazy serves?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just saying that putting a non-thread-safe object inside a `Lazy<T>` does not magically make it thread-safe.

What `Lazy<T>` does for you is provide a thread-safe way to *initialize* the lazy instance, such that every thread sees the same value.

Comment: ,Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Elaborate on what? What thread safety means? The documentation for the `Lazy` class?